# Providing an exact name to a Sequential Node in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to name a Node in a Keras model, but Keras appends additional information to the layer name.

For example, when you create a layer like this with the name "sm_output":

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation='softmax', name="sm_output"))
```

you end up with the softmax output being called

```
sm_output/Softmax
```

How can I name the final output from the model? I need it to fit a standard convention, because this model is interchanged with other models and the calling code can't find the output layer if it's not the same.

Comment: First you can get the output tensor like `model.layers[last_layer_index].output` Then you can rename this tensor.

Answer (score 0):

@Lukeyb You could use `model.layers[-1].name` to access last layer name you set initially. You can change the index of layers to access name of other layers in the model

Please check the example below where name of last layer was accessed.

```
import tensorflow as tf

model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',input_shape=(None, None, 784,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax',name='last_layer')
])

model1.layers[-1].name
```

The output is as follows

```
'last_layer'
```